Date filter in Power BI excluding current month
I'm editing a pre-existing PBI report and trying to figure out why the date filter is behaving a certain way.
There is a slider-style date filter as well as a date slicer. If I put in "last 4 years" in the slicer, the date filter shows a stopping point of May 2024, which is last month. What I'm expecting to see is this current month of June to have some values for the Standard Protect column, but they are all zero:

Now, if I change the slicer, specifically by "clearing" it, I get values which can only come from June, even though the date slider still shows an end date of May 2024:

What should I be looking at to understand what's happening here?

I got this sorted out. The problem was that I needed to refresh the data, I wasn't aware that was a thing. Now I know!
